# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'asdf' for key 'user_username_unique' (SQL: update `user` set `username` = asdf

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

This works on create/store but not on edit/update. I want the user to be updated
and the data already exists in the database, the validation error appears.
like this in the user store, I added the data, and it worked, even if there was already the same data then a validation error appeared, but in a different update if I update only the address then the old username data is still used and if I change the username it also works but it doesn't if I replace the username with an existing username the validation error does not appear and instead displays the following error.
please help me i am still a student!

Error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'asdf' for key 'user_username_unique' (SQL: update `user` set `username` = asdf, `password` = $2y$10$BYdDToN5jCCuRLdZx70YA.BFgyVIWulL8n/bv5C3VxOVCw6WBN.kO, `kota_id` = 1505, `kecamatan_id` = 1505013, `desa_id` = 1505013004, `user`.`updated_at` = 2022-04-09 14:25:03 where `id` = 4)

User Migration:

```
Schema::create('user', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('nik')->unique()->nullable();
    $table->string('nama')->nullable();
    $table->string('telp')->unique()->nullable();
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
    $table->string('foto')->nullable();
    $table->string('username')->unique();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->enum('level', ['user','admin'])->default('user');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('provinsi_id')->nullable();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('kota_id')->nullable();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('kecamatan_id')->nullable();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('desa_id')->nullable();
    $table->text('alamat')->nullable();
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

User Controller Store

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validasi = $request->validate([
        'username' => ['required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:30', 'unique:user'],
        'email' => ['required', 'email', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:user'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8'],
        'nama' => ['required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:50'],
        'nik' => ['required', 'string', 'min:16', 'max:16', 'unique:user'],
        'telp' => ['required', 'string', 'min:12', 'max:13', 'unique:user'],
        'provinsi_id' => ['required'],
        'kota_id' => ['required'],
        'kecamatan_id' => ['required'],
        'desa_id' => ['required'],
        'foto' => ['mimes:jpeg,jpg,png'],
        'level' => ['required'],
        'alamat' => ['required'],
        ]);
    $validasi['password'] = Hash::make('password');
    $create = User::create($validasi);
    if($request->hasFile('foto')){
        $request->file('foto')->move('images/',$request->file('foto')->getClientOriginalName());
        $create->foto = $request->file('foto')->getClientOriginalName();
        $create->save();
    }

    return redirect()->route('user.index');
}
```

User Controller Update

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);
    $validasi = $request->validate([
        'username' => ['required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:30', 'unique:user,id'],
        'email' => ['required', 'email', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:user,id'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'max:20'],
        'nama' => ['required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:50'],
        'nik' => ['required', 'string', 'min:16', 'max:16', 'unique:user,id'],
        'telp' => ['required', 'string', 'min:12', 'max:13', 'unique:user,id'],
        'provinsi_id' => ['required'],
        'kota_id' => ['required'],
        'kecamatan_id' => ['required'],
        'desa_id' => ['required'],
        'foto' => ['mimes:jpeg,jpg,png'],
        'level' => ['required'],
        'alamat' => ['required'],
    ]);
    $validasi['password'] = Hash::make('password');
    $user->update($validasi);
    if($request->hasFile('foto')){
        $request->file('foto')->move('images/',$request->file('foto')->getClientOriginalName());
        $user->foto = $request->file('foto')->getClientOriginalName();
        $user->save();
     }

    return redirect()->route('user.index');
}
```

Comment: just to be sure, how much you know about sql `unique` constraint? `$table->string('username')->unique();` applies unique constraint on that column which prevents any duplicate `username` input.

Comment: you have to provide the actual id to ignore. try this. `'unique:user,id,'.$id` if its email `'unique:user,email,'.$id`

Comment: @user3532758 it's not working SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id7' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `user` where `id7` = 1234512345123452)

Comment: Notice the comma after id before the string ends. `unique:user,id,'.$id` . id7 indicates that you forgot the comma. And make sure you repeat the rule for all unique fields.

Answer (score 2):

## The Cause

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'asdf' for key 'user_username_unique' (SQL: update `user` set `username` = asdf, `password` = ...)
```

The error above **thrown by the SQL Database** saying that you are trying to update a record **but  the `username` is already exists** and used by another record.

This is why I ask for clarification, **"how much you know about sql `unique` constraint?"**

You could somewhat avoid the error from arising by validating the user input using Laravel Validation using `unique` rule:

```
$request->validate(['username' => [..., 'unique:user'], ...]);
```

You already have one and a perfect working sample on your `store` function. The declaration above told Laravel to check whether we have existing `username` in `user` table or not.

However, your `update` function does not validate `username` field as you have declared them:

```
 $request->validate(['username' => [..., 'unique:user,id'],...]);
```

The declaration above means *"check if `username` already exists on `user` table **on `id` column**."* Laravel then checks `username` on `id` column. Hence, Laravel thought that `username` doesn't exists on the table. Fortunately, you have declared on your migration to ensure `username` to be unique - and thats why you have that particular error.

## The solution

You can either exclude the `username` from edit procedure or update your validation to exclude the used `username` from firing validation error.

```
$validasi = $request->validate([
            'username' => ['required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:30',
                           Rule::unique('user')->ignore($user->id)], ...]);
```

`Rule::unique('user')->ignore($user->id)` means Laravel must ensure the `username` is not used by no record other than with given primary key `$user->id`.

Replacing `'unique:user,id'` with `Rule::unique('user')->ignore($user->id)` will ensure that the `username` is unique against all the other records except the current one. This is what Andreas Bilz meant with his link to [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-unique).

Note:

- Ellipsis (`...`) are to shorten the statements
- You should keep watch for SQL Error should your application used by multiple users and consider transaction whenever atomicity become mandatory (see: [transaction](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database#database-transactions))
- Be kind to people trying to help

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is to have a rule in place that "excludes" the current user to be checked against the uniqueness of the properties it owns already: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-unique

Comment: i've read it over and over and it frustrates me, do you have any other solution?

Comment: Read through the paragraph "Forcing A Unique Rule To Ignore A Given ID" and possibly this snippet might be helpful: `Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user)`

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code, it will not check the records corresponding to that id which you have passed.
Suppose you are updating a user whose **id = 1, username = 'test' and email = test@test.com** you want to update the username name then **it will not give error of email because it will check all the other records except id = 1**

```
$user = User::find($id);
$validasi = $request->validate([
    'username' => 'required|string|min:3|max:30|unique:user,username,'.$id,
    'email' => 'required|email|string|max:255|unique:user,email,'.$id,
    'password' => 'required|string|min:8|max:20',
    'nama' => 'required|string|min:3|max:50',
    'nik' => 'required|string|min:16|max:16|unique:user,nik,'.$id,
    'telp' => 'required|string|min:12|max:13|unique:user,telp'.$id,
    'provinsi_id' => 'required',
    'kota_id' => 'required',
    'kecamatan_id' => 'required',
    'desa_id' => 'required',
    'foto' => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png',
    'level' => 'required',
    'alamat' => 'required',
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I solved it. The problem was with seeders. When performing `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed` if you have dummy data that matches with your seeds, then the error appears.

**How to solve:**

Go to **database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php**.
Remove `UsersTableSeeder::class` and let the dummy users to migrate.
Run `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed`.
**Problem SOLVED.**